# Mechanize Page.Form.Action POST for multiple INPUT tags with same NAME / VALUE

Tags: ruby, mechanize

Need to post to existing web page (no login required) and post parameters for submit where multiple submit forms tags exist and contains identical  tags with the same NAME and VALUE tags; for example, on the same page this INPUT Submit is repeated 3 times under different FORM tags:

`< INPUT TYPE='Submit' NAME='submit_button' VALUE='Submit Query' >`

My Ruby code runs ok for identifying the fields on the form tags, but fails on the page.forms[x].action post with 405 HTTPMethodNotAllowed for https://pdb.nipr.com/html/PacNpnSearch -- unhandled response.

Ruby code:

```
class PostNIPR2
def post(url)
 button_count = 0
 agent = Mechanize.new
 page = agent.get(url)
 page.forms.each do |form|
  form.buttons.each do |button|
   if(button.value == 'Submit Query')
    button_count = button_count + 1
   if (button_count == 3) 
    btn_submit_license = button.name
    puts button
    puts btn_submit_license 
    puts button.value
   end
  end
 end    
end
begin
 uform = page.forms[1]
 uform.license = "0H20649"
 uform.state = "CA"
 uform.action = 'https://pdb.nipr.com/html/PacNpnSearch'
rescue Exception => e
 error_page = e.page
end
page = agent.submit(uform)
end
url = "https://pdb.nipr.com/html/PacNpnSearch.html"
p = PostNIPR2.new
p.post(url)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your question how to select that button? If so:

```
form.button_with(:name => 'submit_button')
```

or submit the form like this:

```
next_page = form.submit form.button_with(:name => 'submit_button')
```

Also you are changing the form's action for some reason and that will explain the 405s

Comment: button_with works ok; my question was form.submit together with the form paramaters (e.g., licence, state).

Comment: I just got it working with the follow code change:def post(url)

 btn_submit_license = ''
 button_count = 0
 license_form = ''
 agent = Mechanize.new
 page = agent.get(url) 
 begin
  form = agent.page.form_with(:name => "license_form")
  form.license = "0H20649"
  form.state = "CA"
  button = form.button_with(:value => "Submit Query")
  response = agent.submit(form, button)
  puts response.save('/Users/my/com/ruby/nipr-result.html')
 end 
end

url = "https://pdb.nipr.com/html/PacNpnSearch.html"
p = PostNIPR2.new
p.post(url)

end

Comment: Rather than put code in a comment, consider updating your question or posting an answer. Also, it's still not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, sorry about the comment code - the question was to have the `form.license` and `form.state` updated with the input params then have the `form.submit` post the `form.button_with(:name => 'Submit Query'` - I did this and received the `405 HTTPMethodNotAllowed`, while for https://pdb.nipr.com/html/PacNpnSearch -- `unhandled response`. But now I have changed the code to `agent.page.form_with(:name => 'license_form')` which now correctly finds the form I need to post to; then I get the `form.button_with(:value => 'Submit Query')` and then utilize the `agent.submit(form, button)`. Now I get the correct result.